# The gradient $\nabla u$ of $u\in W^{1,p}(M;N)$ is tangent to $N$ almost everywhere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $M,N$ be (compact) Riemannian manifolds. $N$ is viewed as an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb R^K$. The Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(M;N)$ is defined as
$$
W^{1,p}(M;N):=\{ u\in W^{1,p}(M;\Bbb R^K)\ |\ u(x)\in N \quad\text{almost every   } x\in M\}.
$$

> How do we show that $\nabla u$, the weak derivatives of $u$, belong to the tangent space $T_{u(x)}N$ almost every $x$?

I don't know if this is essential or not, but I am willing to assume that the structure/dimension of $M,N$ admits the approximation of every $u\in W^{1,p}(M;N)$ by smooth functions $u_n\in C^{\infty}_c(M;N)$.

Comment: The first thing to do is to define what you mean by “tangent”

Comment: @DeaneYang I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I mean in the usual sense, i.e. we identify $T_{u(x)}N$ as a subspace of $T_{u(x)}\Bbb R^K$.

Comment: sorry. I misread it. I suggest finding an exposition of the theory of harmonic maps. Usually, this is the first thing discussed.

Comment: @DeaneYang Do you perhaps have some recommendation for this kind of article? The ones that I found either don't mention this explicitly or just take it for granted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differential of a Sobolev map between manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108808/differential-of-a-sobolev-map-between-manifolds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will assume $N$ is closed, while $M$ may have boundary. Also let $n = \mathrm{dim}(M).$

If $n \leq p < \infty$ we have $C^{\infty}(M;N)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(M;N),$ so let $u_k$ be a sequence of smooth functions tending to $u \in W^{1,p}(M;N).$ Now let $x \in M$ and let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a choice of coordinates on $U \ni x.$ Then we get each $\partial_{x_i} u_k \rightarrow \partial_{x_i}u$ in $L^2(U;\mathbb R^{K+K})$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ (here each $\partial_{x_i} u_k$ takes values in $TN \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{K+K}$). Then passing to a subsequence we can assume each $\partial_{x_i}u_k \rightarrow \partial_{x_i}u$ almost everywhere on $U,$ so we get $\partial_{x_i}u(y) \in T_{u(y)}N$ for almost every $y \in U.$ Doing this around each point implies the result.

Note this argument only requires $u \in W^{1,p}_{\mathrm{loc}}(M,N)$ with $n \leq p,$ so in particular this also establishes the $p = \infty$ case.

Comment: Are you sure that $C^{\infty}(M;N)$ is always dense in $W^{1,p}(M;N)$ whenever $p<\infty$? I've read that this is the case for $p\ge\dim M$ but I thought there are some counter examples when $p<\dim M$.

Comment: @BigbearZzz My bad, it seems like proving density is more subtle than I had thought. In that case my argument only works for $p \geq \mathrm{dim}(M),$ so I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Also I don't quite understand the part "$\nabla u_k \rightarrow u$ in $L^2(M;\mathbb R^{K+K}).$" Is that a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Yeah that's a typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but I have one more question. In the place that you wrote $L^2(M;\mathbb R^{K+K})$ shouldn't it be $L^2(M;\mathbb R^{nK})$ instead?

Comment: @BigbearZzz $K+K$ should be correct, because we can embed $TN \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{K+K}$ by noting $N \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^K$ and so we can view each $T_pN \leq \mathbb R^K.$ This is just a technicality though, which isn't too important.

Comment: Technically speaking, isn't it the case that it's $\nabla_v u\in TN$? What I had in mind is that $\nabla u\in T^*M \otimes TN$ hence my question about the dimension.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Yup, you're right. I suppose in this case it would be best to look at $u$ locally in terms of coordinates, so each $\partial_{x_i} u$ is a map into $TN.$ I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another argument. Every Sobolev function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a representative which is absolutely continuous on almost all lines parallel to coordinate axes. This is Theorem 2 in Section 4.9.2 in  L. C. Evans, R. F.  *Measure theory and fine properties of functions.*  Studies in Advanced Mathematics. CRC Press, Boca Raton, FL, 1992. Now $u\in W^{1,p}(M,\mathbb{R}^K)$, when represented in a local coordinate system maps line segments parallel to coordinate system to rectifiable curves in $N$ and hence the derivative of $u$ maps tangent vectors to vectors tangent to rectifiable curves in $N$ and hence tangent to $N$. This implies that $Du$ maps $T_xM$ to $T_{u(x)}N$ for almost all $x\in M$.

Regarding the last comment in the question, in general you cannot assume that $u\in W^{1,p}(M,N)$ can be approximated by smooth maps $C^\infty(M,N)$. For example $u:W^{1,p}(B^n,S^{n-1})$, $u(x)=x/|x|$ cannot be approximated by smooth maps $C^\infty(B^n,S^{n-1})$ when $n-1\leq p<n$ and one can easily modify this example to have a mapping $u\in W^{1,p}(S^{n},S^{n-1})$ that cannot be approximated by maps in $C^\infty(S^{n},S^{n-1})$ when $n-1\leq p<n$. This is a result due to Schoen and Uhlenbeck. For references and related results see for example this
 [survey papepr](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/Sobolev%20mappings%20between%20metric%20spaces3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am particularly interested in results about Sobolev space on (compact) Riemannian manifolds without boundary. Could you recommend me some survey paper or article? I'd like to know also if things like Rellich-Kondrachov theorem or Poincare inequality holds on such space.

Comment: Both Rellich-Kondrachv theorem, Sobolev and Poincare inequalities hold on compact manifolds without bounay, just like in the Euclidean case. You use a finite atlas and partition of unity to localize the function and then the results follow from the corresponding Euclidean results.  However, writing details is quite tedious and I am not aware of a good reference that would do everything in details.

Comment: Does your approach work for $p < \dim M$? thanks.

Comment: Any dimension since absolute continuity on lines is true for any $n$ and any $p\geq 1$.